# Kendo Map does not work with MapQuest anymore

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, layer, mapquest

MapQuest has released a new version on 11 July, 2016. And the Kendo Map does not work anymore. 
At the current, my project is facing this problem. Please preference to Telerik demo to get more detail about the issue:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/diagrams-and-maps/map/how-to/custom-bubble-layer-symbols

[image]

After investigating it, seems like Kendo Map does not support the urlTemplate of MapQuest.

The urlTemplate of MapQuest in the old version that Kendo Map was working normally

```
urlTemplate: "http://otile3.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/#= zoom #/#= x #/#= y #.png",
```

BUT, after MapQuest releases the new version, Kendo Map gets the problem as the image above. I don't know if the urlTemplate is still supported by Kendo Map? Or, does MapQuest change to a new urlTemplate? If yes, what is it?

I have contacted both MapQuest and Telerik Kendo Map support teams, but there is no response till now.

Could you give me some advices or share your experience that can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

MapQuest no longer supports direct tile access. The Kendo team may have more details about a fix using one of the [supported mapping sdks](http://devblog.mapquest.com/2016/06/15/modernization-of-mapquest-results-in-changes-to-open-tile-access/) or another tile source. Sorry for the inconvenience.